# MFMailComposeViewController not compiling for arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm64

I am trying to migrate an old app to compile with 64bit and encountered a problem.

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in ImagesResultsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to send an Email from the Iphone

I have

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

in the header and

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = nil;
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    }
```

And then I use the picker to send an Email.

I have MessageUI.framework included in the project
This is working fine if I compile on armv7 and armv7s but not on arm64

Thanks for any help

Comment: which SDK are you targeting?

Comment: @nielsbot I have iOS Deployment Target set to iOS 7.0

Comment: is there I 64-bit version of iOS 7? try 8.0

Comment: @nielsbot I tried, same issue. Thanks

Comment: try building for simulator vs device?

Comment: @nielsbot problem is, this app has many C++ libraries that are not supported on the simulator, so I can only try on the device.

Comment: hm you could remove arm64 from your architectures

Comment: That would make it work but apple do not allow submission without 64 bit anymore. That was the whole point of this work. Thanks

Comment: sorry out of ideas :)